# How do I buy a car in Don't get fired?

Tags: dont-get-fired

In **Don't get fired**, I already double checked all tutorials, clicked everywhere and couldn't find out how to buy a car.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Please, if you are going to down-vote the question, at least write a comment why you are doing that and/or how should I improve the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A car can be purchased for 70,000 when you randomly receive the event.

The event has a chance of happening when you click on the blue speech bubble with `...` that sometimes appears above your character's head.

Clicking the negative option for this event will have no consequences.

Purchasing the car will increase your rank from Slave to Lower Class and give you the +3% promotion chance bonus, as well as unlocking other events, namely marriage.

Comment: The question about the car just appeared in the game when I got the job related to team leader. 
It seems extremely difficult to buy a car or other stuff based on the amount of money involved. I guess the developer made it that way so you would buy coins in the in-app store.

Comment: @vianna77 by team leader I'm guessing you mean assistant manager? I don't think the car is meant to be an early game purchase, once you can get to DGM or higher a few times you'll have plenty of money. Try to get extra promotion chance by getting fired in different ways, challenges are great for money, try purchasing skills, I had most if not all of the 16k skills when I got the car